# Turning my function into an async function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

In my Angular application I have a method whose execution I need to defer until a value becomes available from the backend:  This is the method:

```
redrawGrid(params: any): void {
    params.node.childFlower.setRowHeight( (this.globalRowCount * 34 ) + 34) ;
    this.gridOptions.api.onRowHeightChanged();
}
```

I need this method to execute AFTER this.globalRowCount (as a global value returned from a service) returns from the backend.

The variable this.globalRowCount is coming from a subscription to an observable

```
this.userlistService.childRowLength.subscribe( (num: number) => {
    this.globalRowCount = num;
    console.log(this.globalRowCount + ' globalRowCount after num assigned');
});
```

I read that I could make this function async and use await...?  How would I do this?

Comment: what have you tried? Have you looked at promises?

Comment: The change needs to be made to the code that actually calls `redrawGrid`. The code should only call `redrawGrid` once `this.globalRowCount` was updated. You don't actually have to change `redrawGrid` at all (at least not as far as I can tell given the information you provided).

Comment: Async await needs to happen in the function where you get globalrowCount not in the function that uses it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can return a `Promise`, which is how all the cool kids are doing the async in JavaScript and TypeScript these days.

```
function redrawGrid(params: any): PromiseLike<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        params.node.childFlower.setRowHeight((rowCount * 34) + 34);
        this.gridOptions.api.onRowHeightChanged();
        resolve();
    });
}
```

You can also handle errors and call `reject` in there if something goes wrong, which lets your consumers handle any problems.

This won't change when this code executes though, so if you want this to be called *after* some other async operation, you're really looking to call it when the other async operation resolved... I don't know the API you are using, but we're talking about something like the following psuedo code...

```
redrawGrid(params: any): void {
    // the getGlobalRowCount is now the method returning a promise
    this.getGlobalRowCount()
        .then((rowCount) => {
            params.node.childFlower.setRowHeight((this.globalRowCount * 34) + 34);
            this.gridOptions.api.onRowHeightChanged();
            resolve();
    });
}
```

Comment: Actually the cool kid use observables or async await but I still like promises too

Comment: @rjustin throwing down the challenge. I respect that.

Comment: I would vote for using Observables in Angular2. i.e. https://developer.telerik.com/topics/web-development/introduction-observables-angular-developers/

Comment: I think I understand the general idea, but I am not awaiting for another async operation to finish.  The variable comes from a subscription to an observable.  I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You may be confused on where to use async await but you'll likely want something like this:

```
async redrawParentFunction(){
    if(!this.globalRowCount)
        this.globalRowCount = await http.get(....).toPromise()//some promise
    this.redrawGrid(....)
}

redrawGrid(params: any): void {

        params.node.childFlower.setRowHeight( (this.globalRowCount * 34 ) + 34) ;
        this.gridOptions.api.onRowHeightChanged();

}
```

Async goes in front of the function name which is required.

await goes before the promise instead of a then().